# ASP.NET MVC - return View with url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following code:

GET method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(string username)
{
     // something here
}
```

POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(UserEditViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // all right, save and redirect to user list
        return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }

    // something wrong with model, return to form
    return View(model);
}
```

It works fine, but get parameter in URL of browser `username=bla-bla-bla` is lost. So, user can't copy that link to open this page again. Is is possible to restore URL param? If I do redirect then I lost model with mistakes...

Comment: Not entirely clear what is not working. Are you saying that if you type "localhost:1234/User/EditUser?username=john", "john" is not making it to the Get action?

Comment: I mean if user clicks "refresh" then this page will not opened. Or he can't add it to favorites, copy and paste to other tab, send to friend....

Comment: So `localhost:1234/User/EditUser?username=john` loads a page without `?username=john` in the address bar?

Comment: If you mean the parameter to your method is gone, just add it to your post.  `public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(UserEditViewModel model, string username)`  -  However, be aware this could make it easy for someone to simply change the username.  If you mean that when you redirect to UserList you're losing the parameters, then you need to add those to the route parameters of the redirect.  Also, make sure your FORM method url contains your paramters.

Answer (score 0):

To "forward" query string parameters to another URL, you can add them as route values. When a route encounters parameters that are undefined, it will add them as query string parameters.

The only thing extra you need to do is convert the query string parameters back into route values for the requested route, and to ensure that the parameters you want to use as query string values are *not defined* in the route.

### NameValueCollectionExtensions

Unfortunately, the `Request.QueryString` parameter is a `NameValueCollection`, but the route values have a separate structure `RouteValueDictionary` that the query string needs to be translated to. So we make a simple extension method to make this easier.

```
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValueDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
    {
        var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (var k in col.AllKeys)
        { 
            dict[k] = col[k];
        }  
        return dict;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(UserEditViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // all right, save and redirect to user list including
        // query string parameters.
        return RedirectToAction("UserList", this.Request.QueryString.ToRouteValueDictionary());
    }

    // something wrong with model, return to form
    return View(model);
}
```

This assumes you are using the `Default` route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Since it has no `username` route value defined, passing a `username` route value to `RedirectToAction` will cause it to add it to the URL as a query string parameter.

```
/SomeController/UserList?username=bla-bla-bla
```